# Incorrect syntax near '=' sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sp-executesql

I need to `delete` all `rows` in some `table` `where` value is empty string.(I have multiple table which got similar name).

I tryed to execute those sql statement which is in string:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @emptyValue AS NVARCHAR(1) =''    
set @sql = N'DELETE FROM SampleTable WHERE Value='+@emptyValue+''
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

But it's throw me error `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '='.`

I tryed to figure it out about an hour now.
Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
Here's what I get after deleting last quota. `@tableName` is `nvarchar(MAX)`.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing string concatenation, [parameterize](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the call to `sp_executesql`, for Sql Injection and other reasons (including caching of query plans, and not having to worry about escaping quotes :-):

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @emptyValue AS NVARCHAR(1) ='';
set @sql = N'DELETE FROM SampleTable WHERE Value=@emptyValue';
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@emptyValue NVARCHAR(1)', @emptyValue = @emptyValue;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5007c/1)

Comment: If he must use exec then this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have two quotes:

```
set @sql = N'DELETE FROM SampleTable WHERE Value='+@emptyValue+''
```

Change it to:

```
set @sql = N'DELETE FROM SampleTable WHERE Value='+@emptyValue
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce8e3/4

Comment: with single quota at the end the rest of my script is treated as string.

Comment: @harry180 - you have two single quotes.  You only need one.  I have included a SQL Fiddle to demonstrate my code working.

Comment: @DarrenDavies It appears what is in your SQLFiddle is not the same as the code you've posted here. From your fiddle: `set @sql = N'DELETE FROM SampleTable WHERE Value='+@emptyValue+''` - Note the two quotes at the end, not one.

Comment: After deleting quotas from the end it's still returns same error :(

Comment: I think the problem is that from the default value assigned to `@emptyValue` in the question, it's inferred that the Value column is a string - you need to surround it in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I'd go with [StuartLC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22066532/1220971) - parameters are clearly the way to go.

Just to show you what to do if you have no choice but to go this way, you can escape the single quotes. The quotes are necessary as the Value column appears to be a string (inferred from the default value set to `@emptyValue` in the question).

To escape a single quote, you need another single quote. Give this a try:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @emptyValue AS NVARCHAR(1) = ''
set @sql = N'DELETE FROM SampleTable WHERE Value='''+@emptyValue+''''
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Note you could always `PRINT @sql` to see the script, rather than blindly trying to run it.