# Concatenate Date in sql Dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, concatenation

I am trying to execute a dynamic query in which I am concatenating a date but failed in doing

```
DECLARE @pStartDate datetime  
DECLARE @pEndDate datetime
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX)
```

Dynamic query1

```
set @query = 'Select * from Table1 From tblEvent
              Where (EventDate Between' + @pStartDate + ' and ' + @pEndDate +')'
Exec(@query)
```

Error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Dynamic query2

```
set @query = 'Select * from Table1 From tblEvent
              Where (EventDate Between' + cast(@pStartDate as varchar) + ' and ' + cast(@pEndDate as varchar) +')'
Exec(@query)
```

Error

> Incorrect syntax near 1 [1 stands for whatever date I passed to @pStartDate]

Please suggest me how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **really proper** way to do this would be to use a **parametrized query** and having `sp_executeSql` execute this:

```
DECLARE @pStartDate datetime  
DECLARE @pEndDate datetime

DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX)

SET @pStartDate = '20080301'
SET @pEndDate = '20080331'

-- if you're setting a NVARCHAR variable - **DO USE** the N'..' prefix!
SET @query = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1
               WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate'

-- execute the dynamic SQL, with a list of parameters, and their values    
EXEC sp_executesql @query, 
                   N'@StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME', 
                   @StartDate = @pStartDate, @EndDate = @pEndDate
```

In that case, there's no fiddling around with string concatenation and missing quotes and messy stuff like that - just a **clear**, properly parametrized query that isn't vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and that performs **much better** since it's execution plan can be reused for subsequent executions.

Comment: +1 Also, here's a [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22066532/772086) with similar info (and a SQL Fiddle).

Answer (score 1):

Add single quote.

Because date or string specify in single quote like this `'12-01-2014'`.

```
set @query = 'Select * from Table1 From tblEvent
Where (EventDate Between''' + @pStartDate + ''' and ''' + @pEndDate +''')'
```